# ValueError: Non-string object detected for the array ordering. Please pass in 'C', 'F', 'A', or 'K' instead

Tags: python, numpy, flask, valueerror

I am trying to convert a coo_matrix to numpy

```
def predict1():

    str_features = [str(x) for x in request.form.values()]
    description= process(str_features[0])
    x1_tfidf_load_sub = pickle.load(open("vocab1.pickle", 'rb'))
    x2_tfidf_load_sub = pickle.load(open("vocab2.pickle", 'rb'))

    description= [description]
    closure= [str_features[1]]

    tfidf_vectorizer1 = TfidfVectorizer(vocabulary=x1_tfidf_load_sub,use_idf=False, norm=None)
    X1_test = tfidf_vectorizer1.fit_transform(description)

    tfidf_vectorizer2 = TfidfVectorizer(vocabulary=x2_tfidf_load_sub,use_idf=False, norm=None)
    X2_test = tfidf_vectorizer2.fit_transform(closure)

    x_test = hstack((X1_test, X2_test))

    x_test_final=x_test.toarray(x_test)
    prediction = model.predict(x_test_final)
```

It keeps showing me the error in the title.
If instead of converting to numpy I simply run:

```
    x_test = hstack((X1_test, X2_test))
    prediction = model.predict(x_test)
```

I get ValueError: dimension mismatch

Plese help.

EDIT:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Pratiksha_S\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\Pratiksha_S\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Pratiksha_S\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Pratiksha_S\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Pratiksha_S\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Pratiksha_S\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Pratiksha_S\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Pratiksha_S\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Pratiksha_S\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Pratiksha_S\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\Pratiksha_S\Desktop\Deployment-flask-master\Deployment-flask-master\app.py", line 65, in predict1
    x_test_final=x_test.toarray(x_test)
  File "C:\Users\Pratiksha_S\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\coo.py", line 323, in toarray
    B = self._process_toarray_args(order, out)
  File "C:\Users\Pratiksha_S\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py", line 1189, in _process_toarray_args
    return np.zeros(self.shape, dtype=self.dtype, order=order)
ValueError: Non-string object detected for the array ordering. Please pass in 'C', 'F', 'A', or 'K' instead
127.0.0.1 - - [03/May/2020 23:14:23] "[37mGET /predict?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=style.css HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [03/May/2020 23:14:23] "[37mGET /predict?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=jquery.js HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [03/May/2020 23:14:23] "[37mGET /predict?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=debugger.js HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [03/May/2020 23:14:23] "[37mGET /predict?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [03/May/2020 23:14:23] "[37mGET /predict?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=ubuntu.ttf HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
```

Here, x_test is the coo matrix, and x_test_final=x_test.toarray(x_test) satisfies the documentation. Also, I am using sparse hstack.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information.  Where's the traceback?  Which variable is `coo_matrix`?  Which `hstack` are you using?

Comment: Does your use of `x_test.toarray(x_test)` conform to the docs?  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.toarray.html#scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.toarray

Comment: `toarray` is a method of sparse matrix, `x_test`.  You don't provide it as an argument as well.  `x_test.toarray()` or `x_test.toarray('F')`, not `x_test.toarray(**x_test**)`.